# Encapsulating Dataset in R Package Function

Tags: r, r-package

When developing R package is it possible to encapsulate dataset within function and export that function. For example:

```
.f <- function(){
  
  utils::data("my_dataset", envir = environment())
  
  function(other_dataset){
    
    some_function(my_dataset, other_dataset)
  }
}

export_fun <- .f()
```

Is it possible to export function `export_fun`? I ask because it seems to me that this way dataset would be loaded only once and not every time the function is called.

Comment: Have you checked out https://r-pkgs.org/data.html? Most package data now is lazy loaded just once the first time it's requested. It's pretty rare that you explicitly call `utils::data` anymore. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: `my_dataset` is `sf` object with points and `some_function` is `sf::st_within`. I'm finding how many specific points are within user provided polygon in shiny app.

Comment: @MrFlick I can use `my_dataset` within package functions without using `utils::data`?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the /data folder in the package. Then the data are exported and need to be documented. For purely local data (e.g. specific method parameters), a simple approach is to define a local data set within an .R file in the package, e.g. `foo.R` and then use it in a function.

```r
.mydata <- c(1.22, 4.33, 5.66)

foo <- function() {
  .mydata  * 2
}
```

Then export function `foo`, while .mydata remains internal.

This method is used in several CRAN packages.